# how to check if binary Tree is balanced by substracting both sides heights

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, nodes, binary-search

my goal is to check if a binary tree is balanced, it is balanced in the case the height of the right and left subtrees differ at most by k, k is a number provided by the user and must be k<=n, n being the number of nodes in the tree.
what am I doing wrong?

```
public boolean isBalanced(BTNode1 root,int k) {
        if(height(root,k)<=k)
            return true;
        
        else return false;
        
        
    }
    
    int height(BTNode1 root,int k){
        if(root==null)
            return 0;
        
        int l = height(root.getLeft(),k);
        
        int r = height(root.getRight(),k);
     
        
        return Math.abs(l-r);
            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `height` function does not return a height, but a *difference* in height. So that means the recursive calls return *differences* and so `l-r` is a difference of differences, which no longer makes any sense, and only gets more meaningless if that return value is again used by the caller to take part in a subtraction.

You need both: the heights of the subtrees, and the difference in heights. The `height` function should return the *height*, while `k` should be used to *verify* the height difference is not excessive -- currently your `height` function does not use `k` at all. If the height difference exceeds `k` you could do any of the following:

1. raise an exception, and have that trapped at the top-level call. Or
2. return an impossible height value, like -10, which to the caller will indicate to abort the process and also return -10, ...etc.

Whichever of these two you choose, the top-level caller should translate that information to true/false.